# Trying to push .match result in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to push `.match()` result into an array, but I don't want an array in an array.

So **is it possible to only get the value that is inside the result array?**

```
$scope.iframes.duration.push($scope.iframes.src[i].match(/data-duration="[^]*?"/g));
```

This is how I do it now; however, I don't want a new array in the original one, I just want the value of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to add the `match` result array elements inside the `duration` array.

```
$scope.iframes.duration = $scope.iframes.duration.concat($scope.iframes.src[i].match(/data-duration="[^]*?"/g));
```

`concat()` doesn't update the actual array, it returns the updated array. To update the array, you can assign the result of `concat` to the array.

Also, the RegEx should be `/data-duration="[^"]*?"/g` to match the value of `data-duration` attribute which is enclosed in quotes.

As there is only one valid attribute having same name, you can safely remove the `g` flag from RegEx.

Comment: It all looked really good and sounded like it must work, but this `$scope.iframes.duration.concat($scope.iframes.src[i].match(/data-duration="[^]*?"/g));` just doesn't work?

Comment: @Goldenowner To update the array, you need to assign the result. Ex. `$scope.iframes.duration = $scope.duration.concat(...`

Answer (score 2):

You could use concat instead of push to concatenate the array with the original one.

Comment: Thanks! I had never heard of that function, but its works perfect :)